# Search for id="* *" in Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I am searching in my Eclipse project for `id="* *"` in order to find something like below in all files of my project

```
id="Text1 Text2"
```

Since space between attribute value needs to be removed I am searching like this to find out all the instances in my project.

But it searches and brings up lots of results since `*` represent any string.

**For example:**

```
id="xyzImg" onLoad="test();" SRC="abc.png"
```

It taking the complete element instead of desired results.

Please suggest me is there any way to get my desired result or is there any online tool that serve the same purpose.

Comment: i tried but its taking as string "asterisk". can you please tell me in much more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to write it here as an answer instead. Try with `*|*`. By asterisk I meant the wildcard symbol.

Comment: Then another suggestion. Try with `Text1.*Text2|Text2.*Text1`. If it doesn't help you this time either, then I would suggest you to read more about regular expressions as I don't know what it is you are trying to find.